# Understanding PSNR value

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm just confused because I'm comparing 3 different images to pick just 1 of 3 images that has the highest quality.

This is what I have tried:

```
PSNR1=psnr(I2Grayscale, I1Grayscale)
PSNR2=psnr(I3Grayscale, I1Grayscale)
PSNR3=psnr(I3Grayscale, I2Grayscale)
```

What I got is PSNR1 = 27, PSNR2 = 29 and PSNR3 = 24. So how do I know which image is best? Because say I inverted PSNR1 to be `psnr(I1Grayscale, I2Grayscale)`, I would still get 27. Please advise if there's something I can add or change to evaluate the quality.

Comment: Please read the docs: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/psnr.html This function compares an image with a noiseless reference. You cannot use it to compare two images and learn which is “better”.